# little XPath for scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

By Chrome I got the XPATH like

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div
```

Sector

```
body > div.off-canvas-wrap > div.inner-wrap.brand-padding > section:nth-child(2) > div > div.row.article-view > div.columns.small-12.medium-7 > div:nth-child(5) > div
```

and class is

```
<div class="columns small-12">
```

can you please generate the XPATH for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="columns small-12"]').extract()
```